# Did I just delete a whole month of work?

Tags: git

I'am a Git noob and I'am actually only using it to save files to Bitbucket. Git was complaining that everything was up-to-date and because it's late and I want to go sleep I just hammered some commands from Stackoverflow and I did a `git reset --hard` without a succesful commit or push and now 30 days of work are gone o__O

Here's what I did:

```
$ git add .
$ git commit -m "I can see light"
*** Please tell me who you are.

Run

  git config --global user.email "you@example.com"
  git config --global user.name "Your Name"

to set your account's default identity.
Omit --global to set the identity only in this repository.

fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'cc@cc-MS-7788.(none)')
$ git push origin master
Password for 'https://...@bitbucket.org': 
Everything up-to-date
```

Then I tried `git status` and saw the changes, but Git kept telling me that everthing is up-to-date.

So I did:

```
$ git reset --hard
HEAD is now at f798df1 starting export fixing
```

And now everything is gone. I tried `git reflog`, but my commit isn't there. Please don't tell me that I just really deleted a month of work o__O

Please advise! Every suggestion is extremly appreciated!!!

Here is the output from `git reflog`. The commit isn't there. "starting export fixing" was the succesful commit on 6 June.

```
$ git reflog
f798df1 HEAD@{0}: checkout: moving from master to master
f798df1 HEAD@{1}: commit: starting export fixing
774c057 HEAD@{2}: commit: meeh
7a66261 HEAD@{3}: commit: finishedTaskCheckup + RunningStop Bug fixed
ca0945a HEAD@{4}: commit: hätte vorher committen sollen... static bei Parsers weggenommen
beb77f0 HEAD@{5}: commit: Version 0.1
68a8874 HEAD@{6}: commit: Updating Ubuntu... omg.. o__O
004910d HEAD@{7}: commit: Verfifiers finished
cb2da07 HEAD@{8}: commit: ConcurrentMap Problem
f0f05e6 HEAD@{9}: commit (initial): dns lookup
```

Comment: Please show the output of `git reflog`.

Comment: You were doing frequent commits to your local repo though, right? ... Right?

Comment: Hmmm, `fatal: unable to auto-detect email address (got 'cc@cc-MS-7788.(none)')`. It didn't even commit, `git log` ~~is empty isn't it?~~ doesn't contain your last commit. That means you never actually commited. It's a good practice to verify the result of your action, *especially* when you're not sure of what's you're doing or how it works. (Because there were no new commit because of failure, `git push` told you it's up to date).

Comment: Wait, that looks like you DO have commits.  Couldn't you just `checkout f798df1` or something?

Comment: Oh, those weren't YOUR commits.  Yeah, you lost everything.  I want to cry for you. :(

Comment: @BlackVegetable Wow. Now that's a real life lesson... wow... Thanks anyway.

Comment: You can commit every 5 minutes if you want, and then when you're finished go back and squash your history into one big commit

Answer (score 9):

Yes, if you went 30 days without ever committing your work, it's lost -- except, of course for your ordinary backup of the machine.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that was what happened.  Yeah, you really need to commit (frequently!) to have a history viewable by reflog.

Answer (score 0):

EPIC WIN!!! I don't know how or why, but a cached version of the files is in the `lost-found/other/` folder. Everything seems up-to-date. Wow, that was a really hard lesson.

@bmargulies Sorry that I removed your answer as the correct one, but I guess if another Git noob has the problem, then he should not stop reading at your answer :D ...  thanks anyway!

Comment: You could have just edited the question and pointed this out as a detail and then you can accept the answer without worrying about someone missing this.